# My CSS is not applied when I change page unless I refresh it

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have made changes in my CSS, but these changes are not applied when I go onto the page.
They ontly appear when I refresh the page.

Here is the CSS I'm talking about:

```
#progress-bar{
    position: absolute;
    top:12%;
    right:50%;
    transform: translate(50%);
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

And when I toggle developper tools I can see this:

[image]

This is the only element that doesn't work.

---

When I reload the page, I have this showing in the toggle developper tools:
[image]

And this is the HTML part that is used to define the progess-bar:

```
<v-col id="progress-bar" cols="7">  
                <v-progress-linear  color="lightblue" height="10" value="25" width="700" rounded></v-progress-linear>
</v-col>
```

Comment: Is all that duplicate CSS expected? Is one of the CSS blocks in your screenshot the correct one? What HTML is there, and what kind of build system or generator do you use? Add some more information and we can better help out.

Comment: the 5th one is the one that should be applied. I use vuetify to load designs

Comment: try adding a new class with those styles something like .progress-bar{...} and use this class in that element.

Comment: I changed the id of the element in the HTML and in the CSS and it solved the problem